# Extracting common numbers from multi-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a little stuck on a JavaScript function that can extract common numbers from a nested array of numbers.

Example input:

```
[[7, 3, 6, 10], [9, 10, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]];
```

Expected output:

```
[3, 10]; // because 3 and 10 are present in all 3 arrays
```

It must work with any arbitrary array of numbers of any size.

Ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It might pay to convert the inner arrays into ever shrinking Sets:

```js
const arr = [[7, 3, 6, 10], [9, 10, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]];

// Expected output:  [3, 10]; // because 3 and 10 are present in all 3 arrays


let final = new Set(arr[0])

for ( i=1; i < arr.length ; i++) {
  final = new Set (arr[i].filter ( x => final.has(x) ))
}

const newArr = Array.from(final)

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: This will not work with arbitrary arrays of numbers. E.g this input (adding an extra array) returns an invalid result `const arr = [[0], [7, 3, 6, 10], [9, 10, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]];`

`// []`

Comment: the empty array is a valid resul @ChrisRich since 0 is not in any other array

Comment: Yes, you are correct :-)

Answer (score -2):

```
var arrays = [[7, 3, 6, 10], [9, 10, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]];

var result = arrays.shift().reduce(function(res, v) {
    if (res.indexOf(v) === -1 && arrays.every(function(a) {
        return a.indexOf(v) !== -1;
    })) res.push(v);
    return res;
}, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result,null,4)+ '</pre>');
```

Comment: This will probably not work, because you are using the first sub element as a comparator. So if you change the input to the following it breaks:

`var arrays = [[1], [7, 3, 6, 10], [9, 10, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]];`;

Maybe you need to use the longest array as the comparator?