# Extract numbers from a n-dimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, nested-lists

Input array: `[1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6, [7, 8, [9]]]], 10]`
Output array: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8, 9, 10]`

Is there a way to get the output array without using multiple loops?

Comment: Tips: [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extracting common numbers from multi-dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73061492/extracting-common-numbers-from-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: @NazeerShaik I do not see any relevance that question has to this one

Comment: If your JS has no Array flat method, `const flat=v=>(!Array.isArray(v))?v:v.reduce((a,v)=>a.concat(flat(v)), []);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add an `infinity` argument to [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to get all the numbers from the many nested arrays.

```js
const data = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6, [7, 8, [9]]]], 10];
const out = data.flat(Infinity);
console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log([1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6, [7, 8, [9]]]], 10].flat(Infinity));
```

Use 'flat' method to flatten the array. Or you can also use underscore module method.